# Trying to animate an element with onClick using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want this div to animate on click using JavaScript.

```
    <div class="Designs">

        <p>Designs</p>

            <div class="Thumbnails" data-animation="animated pulse">

                <a href="images/Halloween/bat.png"><img src="images/Halloween/bat_sm.png" width="140" height="82"/></a>

            </div>


    </div> <!-- End Designs -->
```

Please look at my site to see example

http://mast.salemstate.edu/itc18244/Portfolio/

```
$('.Thumbnails a').on('click', function(e){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var animationName = parent.data('animation') || 'animated pulse';

    parent.addClass(animationName).one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        parent.removeClass(animationName);
    });
```

Comment: You've got javascript errors with your posted code (and on the live site).  The `on` event handler isn't closed properly with a `});` and you shouldn't have the `;` after your `one` event handler.

Comment: His question is "Why doesn't this code work"?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/5cg5j6 --> As Noah Huppert said, you need to close properly your tags. The first error, on line :90, refers exactly to your click event, which is not closed properly. http://prntscr.com/5cg5s2 . By The Way, you have two errors: first, you have a ";" after "{", then, you're not closing the first "{" correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, document ready was missing. See the working demo below.
You could also add data-animation to your div with class .Thumbnail, so you can easily modify the animation just with your HTML markup. See different animation for "Designs".

You can find it also at jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/onhswjxu/).

```js
$(function () {
    var animationend = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

    $('.Thumbnails').on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var animationName = $this.data('animation') || 'animated bounce' ;
        
        $this.addClass(animationName).one(animationend, function () {;
            $this.removeClass(animationName);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
@charset"UTF-8";
 #container {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
body {
    /*background-image: url(images/bg.png);*/
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
name, h3 {
    color: black;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
name {
    font-size: 51px;
}
h3 {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
h2 {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
p {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    max-width: 960px;
}
#float {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
img {
    min-width: 246px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
/*-----------------------*/

/* Navigation */
 .nav {
    height:auto;
    margin: 0 .3em 0 0;
    display:inline;
    display:inline-block;
}
/* specifying the nav list horizontal */
 .nav li {
    display: inline;
    font-size:16px;
    padding: 0 0 0 15.8em;
}
.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* ---------------------------- */

/* Designs_Drawings Div ------ */
 #content .Designs_Drawings {
    width: 680px;
    height: 160px;
    margin: 8em auto 3em auto;
}
#content .Designs {
    background-color: #CCC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 1em;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
#content .Designs p {
    text-align: right;
    /* Top,Right,Down,Left */
    margin: .5em 1em 0 0;
}
#content .Designs .Thumbnails {
    width: 143px;
    height: 95px;
    background-color: blue;
    /* Give thumb div Border/position */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    /*---------------------*/
    /* Top,Right,Down,Left */
    margin: .5em 0 0 1em;
    /* Curves div Corners */
    border-radius: 1em;
}
/* Drawings Div ------ */
 #content .Drawings {
    background-color: #CCC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 1em;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-350deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-350deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-350deg);
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
#content .Drawings p {
    text-align: right;
    /* Top,Right,Down,Left */
    margin: .5em 1em 0 0;
}
#content .Drawings .Thumbnails {
    width: 143px;
    height: 95px;
    /* Give div Border */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: .5em 0 0 1em;
    /* Curves div Corners */
    border-radius: 1em;
}
/* End Designs_Drawings Div */

/* -------------------------*/

/* Photography_WebSites Div */
 #content .Photography_WebSites {
    width: 680px;
    height: 160px;
    margin: 0 auto 4em auto;
}
/* Photography Div ----- */
 #content .Photography {
    background-color: #CCC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 1em;
    -ms-transform: rotate(350deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(350deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(350deg);
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
#content .Photography p {
    text-align: right;
    /* Top,Right,Down,Left */
    margin: .5em 1em 0 0;
}
#content .Photography .Thumbnails {
    width: 143px;
    height: 95px;
    /* Give thumb div Border/position */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    /*---------------------*/
    /* Top,Right,Down,Left */
    margin: .5em 0 0 1em;
    /* Curves div Corners */
    border-radius: 1em;
}
/* Web Sites Div ------ */
 #content .WebSites {
    background-color: #CCC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 1em;
    -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(10deg);
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
#content .WebSites p {
    text-align: right;
    /* Top,Right,Down,Left */
    margin: .5em 1em 0 0;
}
#content .WebSites .Thumbnails {
    width: 143px;
    height: 95px;
    /* Give div Border */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: .5em 0 0 1em;
    /* Curves div Corners */
    border-radius: 1em;
}
/* --------------------*/

/* Big Box Div --------*/
 #content .big_box {
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin: 1em auto 4em auto;
    width: 690px;
    height: 483px;
    position:relative;
    /* Curves div Corners */
    border-radius: 1em;
    /* Give div Border */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
#content .big_box img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
/* ------ */

/* Footer */
 .footer {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    display:inline;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer .info {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer .info li + li::before {
    content:" | ";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: .5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
}
/* specifying the nav list horizontal */
 .footer li {
    display: inline;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.footer .info img {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.2.0/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="Designs_Drawings">
            <div class="Designs">
                <p>Designs</p>
                <div class="Thumbnails" data-animation="animated pulse">
                    <!-- <a href="images/Halloween/bat.png"><img src="images/Halloween/bat_sm.png" /></a>
       <a href="images/Halloween/frankenstein.png"><img src="images/Halloween/frankenstein_sm.png" /></a> -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Designs -->
            <div class="Drawings">
                <p>Drawings</p>
                <div class="Thumbnails" data-animation="animated bounce"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Drawings -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Designs_Drawings -->
        <div class="Photography_WebSites">
            <div class="Photography">
                <p>Photography</p>
                <div class="Thumbnails" data-animation="animated bounce"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Photography -->
            <div class="WebSites">
                <p>Web Sites</p>
                <div class="Thumbnails" data-animation="animated bounce"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- End WebSites -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Photography_WebSites -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wait until the [**document is ready**](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Wrap your code up like so:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var animationName = 'animated bounce';
        var animationend = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

        $('.Thumbnails').on('click', function() {
            $('.Thumbnails').addClass(animationName).one(animationend, function () {;
                $(this).removeClass(animationName);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

You also had a JavaScript error because you were missing a `});` to close the callback.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it works.